# How to retrieve the content of a json file based on a condition?

Tags: java, jquery, json, spring-mvc, datatables

I am creating a messaging system.

I am using Java Spring as the main language of development. To display the messages I am using datatables and jquery.

My problem here is that I don't know if there is a way to retrieve the data conditionally.

this is how I retrieve my data

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#datatables').DataTable({
                "dom": '<"toolbar">frtip',
                "responsive": true,
                "scrollY": "550px",
                "scrollCollapse": true,
                "ajax": "smsMessages.json",
            "aoColumns": [
                {"mData": "sender"},
                {"mData": "content"},
                {"mData": "receiveTime"},
                {"mData": "messageId",
                    "fnCreatedCell": function (nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
                        $(nTd).html("<i class='ti-pencil-alt btn btn-simple btn-edit btn-icon' href='#roleModal' data-toggle='modal' data-mode='edit'></i>\n\
                         <a href='#' type='button' class='btn btn-simple btn-danger btn-icon dt-delete'><i class='ti-close'></i></a>");
                    }
                }
            ],
                language: {
                    "search": "_INPUT_",
                    searchPlaceholder: "Search records"
                }
            });
            demo.initCirclePercentage();
        });
```

This is how it looks like right now: 
[image]

**So, what I want to do here is to make it like a normal inbox of a phone**.

Comment: Why not do it on the server side? or you can check this link: https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()

Comment: normal inbox or textbox?

Comment: I did it on the server side :D thanks sachi.